# Switch construct for combinations of booleans

Tags: java, idioms

Suppose I have *n* boolean values, where *n* is a relatively small number (3-5 or so). Let's say that the values are properties of a class, each of which can be set or unset independently. So, there are 2<sup>*n*</sup> possible combinations. Now I want to distinguish between these combinations in a switch-like fashion. Currently, I usually do something like this:

```
int mask = (bool1 ? 1 : 0) +
           (bool2 ? 2 : 0) +
           (bool3 ? 4 : 0) +
           ... ;
switch (mask) {
    case 0b000:
       // all variables false
    case 0b001:
       // only bool1 true
    case 0b011:
       // only bool1 and bool2 true
    ...
}
```

This works all right, but I do not find it very elegant. Is there some best practice (in Java) or Java idiom for cases like this?

Comment: Why you don't use if statement? It will be much more readable then this switch.

Comment: This **might** be more suitable for [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/), although not voting to close in doubt.

Comment: @DontRelaX Theres a few ways to do ifs, why don't you put your preferred as an answer. And consider how it will look when you have 5 bools.

Comment: Which bit is not elegant enough for you're liking? the building of the mask or the switch or both? Personally, I think it works for 5 quite nicely, but overkill for 3. However, does the content of the `case` blocks repeat?

Comment: @weston. What I don't like about it, is that the meaning of the booleans is not visible in the bit encoding. Also, in a switch with enums, for example, Eclipse warns me if I forgot a case, which is not the case here anymore.

Comment: I can't see why eclipse would do that. Post full example that eclipse warns on.

Comment: @weston. It's a warning, not an error, and something that can be turned of in the preferences. In general I like my IDE to signal potential problems. It's valid Java to omit a case for an enum value, of course.

Comment: Ok, well at least post the warning text. Is it warning that there's no default?

Answer (score 0):

This problem is the reason they invented the [Decorator Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern). The pattern allows for adding "traits" to your class. For instance let's say you have a class Coffee. Each instance of coffee can be with sugar, milk, creamer, sweetener or whipped cream (let's say none of these are mutually exclusive). So instead of having five boolean parameters (one for each trait of coffee). You will have the following hierarchy:

```
public interface Coffee {
  public void drink();
}

public class CupOfCofee implements Coffee {
  public void drink() {
    print("Yumm coffee");
  }
}

abstract class CoffeeDecorator implements Coffee {
  protected Coffee decoratedCoffee;

  public CoffeeDecorator(Coffee decoratedCoffee) {
    this.decoratedCoffee = decoratedCoffee;
  }

  public void drink() {
    decoratedCoffee.drink();
  }
}

// We will provide coffee with sugar as an example.
public class CoffeeWithSugarDecorator extends CoffeeDecorator {
  public CoffeeWithSugarDecorator(Coffee decoratedCoffee) {
    super(decoratedCoffee);
  }

  @Override
  public void drink() {
    print("Yumm sugar");
    super.drink();
  }
}

// Here is how you will initialize a coffee instance with sugar and milk.
Coffee coffee = new CoffeeWithMilk(new CoffeeWithSugar(new CupOfCoffee()));
```

This design makes your code much more readable and extensible by separating the behaviors of each boolean parameter to a separate class. Calling drink will print: "Yumm milk Yumm sugar Yumm coffee"

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This is an interesting design pattern, but I don't think it completely solves the problem. First, it is not possible to specify that some code must be run if a decoration is *not* present. Second, if a `Coffee` is decorated with `CoffeeWithMilk` and `CoffeeWithSugar`, the `drink()` method of both decorations is executed. However, I might want to run code block A if milk is true, code block B if sugar is true, and completely unrelated block C if both sugar and milk are true. Do you if the decorator pattern can be adapted to support this?

Comment: As for code for non-present decoration you can write a class CoffeeWithoutMilk. Then you can write something like new CoffeeWithoutMilk(new CoffeeWithSugar(new CupOfCoffee())); You could write another class called CoffeeWithSugarAndMilk that will do something completely different to CoffeeWithSugar and CoffeeWithMilk. The only problem with this is that users need to be aware to use this class and not to create a new CoffeeWithMilk(new CoffeeWithSugar(new CupOfCoffee()));